# Why is the conv2d output (?, 6, 1, 1) instead of (?, 5, 1, 1)

Tags: tensorflow

What I try to understand is how I can create a convolutional neural network for natural language processing (NLP). To start of, I am using a standard architecture where a filter `F` slides over an input matrix `S` in order to create a convolutional filter map:

[image]

The code below is supposed to implement the convolution step, but I do not quite understand the output dimensions. Please do not get confused from the image. In my code *rows* are word embeddings of words in contrast to the image, where word embeddings are columns.

```py
filter_shape = [
    context_window_size, 
    word_embedding_size, 
    1, 
    num_filters
] # filter_shape: [5, 300, 1, 1]

F = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="F") 
b = tf.Variable(
    tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_filters], name="b")) # b: (1,)

conv = tf.nn.conv2d(      
    input_S,              # input_S: (?, 10, 300, 1)
    F,                    # F: (5, 300, 1, 1)
    strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
    padding="VALID",
    name="conv"
) # conv: (?, 6, 1, 1)

h = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b), name="relu") # h: (?, 6, 1, 1)
```

What I expect for a `[5x300]` sized filter `F` sliding over a `[10x300]` input matrix, where 10 is the number of word-vectors and 300 their respective dimension, is a `[5x1]` convolutional feature vector. If the filter is being placed "at the start" of the input matrix is and sled over it 1 step at a time, the filter can only make 5 steps without exceeding the input matrix.

As you can see from the comments in the code, I am getting a `[6x1]` convolutional feature vector. Because of that I am quite sure that I misunderstood what's happening here.

Why is `conv` dimensioned `(?, 6, 1, 1)` and not `(?, 5, 1, 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you write all the combinations of consecutive intervals (indexing from 0), you will get 6 cases:

`[0,4], [1,5], [2,6], [3,7], [4,8], [5,9]`